# Is there an API for Google's speech recognition technology?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I want to try creating a jQuery slideshow using simple voice commands like "next" or "previous". Is there a way to use Google's voice recognition? I know about Chrome's x-webkit-speech, but I have to click a button to use it.

I tried MIT's WAMI, but I found it slower and less accurate than Google's speech cognition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Google Voice Search works? Is there an API for that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389039/how-google-voice-search-works-is-there-an-api-for-that)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of today this now exists, for Chrome: http://chrome.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/hello-browser.html

([api doc](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#api_description))

Comment: I've created a JavaScript library that wraps this and makes it super-easy to add voice commands to your site or app. Check it out at https://www.talater.com/annyang/

Answer (score 13):

For an easy way to do this with JavaScript, check out [annyang](https://www.talater.com/annyang/), which is a library that makes dealing with speech recognition super-easy.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is what will capture your user's speech and send it some speech server for processing. x-webkit-speech is built into the browser and the browser uses the PC's sound card to capture speech. Javascript/Jquery in a browser alone cannot access the hardware devices. I do not know if Chrome exposes any x-webkit-speech objects in the DOM so you can do capture through Javascript.

That said, people have reverse engineered the Google speech api and used it from code. See http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/ for an example.

Comment: I cant use it in 2015. Is there anyone who got it working?

Answer (score 1):

I found this, I have not personally used it do I don't know if it is entirely what you are looking for but take a look.

http://captico.com/introducing-speech-2-text-api-by-google/2011/03

Comment: Nice interface with that uses this technology is https://www.textfromtospeech.com/uk/voice-to-text/