# speech to text javascript,html5

Tags: javascript, html

How to do speech to text using javascript or html5,i have done it in chrome using x-webkit-speech,but its not supported in other browsers.So is there any api's or libraries to do speech recognition.any answers will be appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search revealed the following for speech to text:

http://speechapi.com

[Is there an API for Google's speech recognition technology?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830203/is-there-an-api-for-googles-speech-recognition-technology)